# swiftで画面遷移時の関数の実行

Tags: swift, iphone

swiftでアプリ開発をしています。

画面A・画面Bとありまして
画面Aから画面Bが呼ばれます。
で、画面Bから画面Aに戻った時に、画面Aの関数を実行したいのですが
方法がわかりません。
画面Aから画面Bは下記のようにStoryboard IDを使ってモーダル表示しています。
【画面A】

```
var selfStoryboard: UIStoryboard?
selfStoryboard = self.storyboard
nex = selfStoryboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Storyboard_ID") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(nex, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

画面Bでは下記のように記述し画面を閉じています。
【画面B】

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
```

このようにして画面を閉じた後に、画面Aの特定な関数を実行するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

モーダルによる画面遷移の場合、遷移元のViewControllerは、`UIViewController`クラスのプロパティ`presentingViewController`で取得できます。
遷移元のViewControllerを、`BaseViewController`、呼びたい`BaseViewController`のメソッドを、`func doAnything()`とすると

```
if let controller = self.presentingViewController as? BaseViewController {
    controller.doAnyThing()
}
```

> 画面Bから画面Aに戻った時に、画面Aの関数を実行したい

戻ったときに実行されるのではなく、上のコードは戻る前に実行されますから、厳密にいうと、あなたのご要望には沿っておりません。それで問題ないとは思いますが、どうしても「閉じた後」でなければならない事情があるのなら、`dismissViewControllerAnimated()`の引数`completion`を使います。

```
let controller = self.presentingViewController as? BaseViewController
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
    controller?.doAnything()
})
```

クロージャ内で`self.presentingViewController`を使うと、うまく動かないので、こういう書き方になっています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。挑戦してみます

Answer (score 0):

viewWillAppear関数を使えばできると思います。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { // 戻ってきた時に実行されます
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // ここにコードを記載
    }
}
```

注意: ただし、このやり方だと、一番最初画面Aが表示された時にも実行されてしまいます。
ですので、

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var isBack = false
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { // 戻ってきた時に実行されます
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // ここにコードを記載
        if isBack {
            // ここにコードを記載
        }
        isBack.toggle()
    }
}
```

のように、変数を定義しておき、条件分岐を使用して戻ったか確かめればいいと思います。
ただ、このやり方ですと

```
C -> A -> B
```

のような構造になっていた場合に、

```
C -> *A -> C -> */A
```

このような順番で遷移したときには *マーク でviewWillAppearが実行されますが、/マーク のところで戻ってきたときに実行されるはずの処理が実行されてしまうので、そのような場合にはBから値渡しをするなど、別のやり方が必要になります。